# Dual booting Windows/Ubuntu, Can't extend Ubuntu Partition into allocated space

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am dual booting Windows/Ubuntu, but for some reason can not extend the Ubuntu Partition into allocated space. I tried gpartion and doing it in windows and have the same issue, I can see the disk space but I am not allowed to extend my Ubuntu partion into the unallocated space, any ideas? Thank you all.[image]

Comment: Do not use Windows to resize Linux partitions. And you must use gparted from Ubuntu's live installer or the gparted live ISO as bootable device. You cannot edit partitions that are mounted.

Comment: @oldfred has the only correct answer here. You must boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD, or a gparted CD, and perform the resizing that way. Cheers, Al